# Least square with Frobenius norm regularization

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

$$
\begin{align} f_i &= \operatorname*{argmin}_f \| Af - d \| ^2_{l2} + λ \| P_X(f) - L_r(P_X(f_{i-1})) \|_F^2 \\[8pt] &=M_4^{-1}(A^Hd+\lambda P_X^*(L_r(P_X(f_{i-1})))) \end{align}
$$

where
$$
M_4(f)\equiv A^HAf+\lambda P_X^*(P_X(f))
$$

And $P_X$ is an operator that maps a vector $f$ into a matrix, and $L_r$ is an operator that returns a low-rank approximation of a matrix, so the regularization term
$$
\|P_X(f) - L_r(P_X(f_{i-1}))\|_F^2
$$
is the low-rank approximation error.

I am trying to understand why $M_4^{-1}$ can be written as the above. And why $M_4^{-1}$ is called pseudoinverse.

Actually this is from Eq.18 of this [file](https://sipi.usc.edu/reports/pdfs/Originals/USC-SIPI-443.pdf), if you want more background.

Comment: I changed $$ argmin_f \lVert Af-d\rVert^2_{l2}, $$ coded as `argmin_f \lVert Af-d\rVert^2_{l2}` to $$ \operatorname*{argmin}_f \| Af-d\|^2_{l2}, $$ coded as `\operatorname*{argmin}_f \| Af-d\|^2_{l2}`. The effect of \operatorname{} differs from that of \text{} or \mathrm{} not only in the way in which the subscript $f$ is formatted, as seen in the example above, but also in having context-depended horizontal spacing (not clearly visible in this particular example, but conspicuous is some others). Also$\ldots\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots$the difference between the effects of `\lVert` and `\rVert`, on the one hand, and `\|` on the other, are not so conspicuous in this particular example but are clearly visible in others.

Comment: Many of these differences are not noticed by most (although they effect some of us the way a spelling error does) but if you look at the same thing written in two different fonts and think one of them is clearly easier to read or aesthetically better, it's because of a large number of little things like this.